# Insert many records into a MySQL table with an AUTO_INCREMENT with a single query

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, luhn

I would like to be able to insert a large number of sequential records into a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field, setting the value of another field to a constant value for all the inserted rows, using a single query.

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE CardNumbers (
    First15 BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CheckDigit DECIMAL(1, 0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (First15)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=123456789012345;
```

I would like to set the `CheckDigit` to `0` for all of these to start, and then [calculate it later](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) from the `First15`.

I imagine a query like:

```
INSERT INTO `CardNumbers` (CheckDigit)
SELECT 0 FROM (...) LIMIT 1000000;
```

Where `(...)` creates an infinite set of rows or similar.

Comment: `INSERT INTO CardNumbers (CheckDigit) VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0)...., (0)` - something like this? I don't completely understand what you mean, but the snippet above will insert 0 for CheckDigit value and number of times it does that is number of (0) there are. If you need something like specifying a number for how many records you want to create, a function would be required.

Comment: The example `INSERT` I provided was meant to insert 1 million rows.

Comment: Well, your question isn't exactly clear. If you're wondering how to efficiently insert 1 million rows - you don't do it in 1 query. You do it in batches, using transactions and prepared statements. You prepare a statement and execute it, binding different value(s) to it. Every 1000 inserts, you commit a transaction and start a new one. That's how you make it quick and efficient. But since I don't know whether that's what you're after, I can't help further. Can you provide more details?